# how i can show the number after period

Tags: android, period

i calculate a tow number and i get this answer  9.144E-4
how i can show the real number in android

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by a "tow number", but 9.144E-4 is equivalent to 0.0009144

Answer (score 0):

Look at [java.text.NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)